# How do I setup a robots.txt which allows all pages EXCEPT the main page?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

If I have a site called http://example.com, and under it I have articles, such as:
http://example.com/articles/norwegian-statoil-ceo-resigns

Basically, I don't want the text from the frontpage to show on Google results, so that when you search for "statoil ceo", you ONLY get the article itself, but not the frontpage which contains this text but is not of the article itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you did that, then Google could still display your home page with a note under the link saying they couldnt crawl the page. This is because robots.txt doesnt stop a page being indexed. You could noindex the home page, though personally I wouldnt recommend it.